# SQL query: Selecting an entry from one table and adding values from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

hotels and hotel_rooms

I'm trying to get a table with the hotel name and the free rooms.

```
SELECT h.Hotelname, r.FreeRooms
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN hotel_room r ON r.H_ID = h.H_ID
WHERE r.H_ID = h.H_ID
```

gives me something like

```
Hotel1    27
Hotel1    14
Hotel1    9
Hotel2    7
Hotel2    21
```

but what I actually want is to add all those values so I get:

```
Hotel1    50
Hotel2    28
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: you're looking for a `LEFT JOIN ... where r.[some value] IS NULL`

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause seems rather redundant.

Comment: My misunderstanding. I didn't realize that it was a total number of free rooms. I though that the number was the room ID (so I thought that you were looking for which rooms were free in each hotel).

Comment: @Wiseguy with my original misunderstanding of the requirements it wasn't. I thought they were just looking for free rooms. WHERE ... NULL would have only given non-booked rooms.

Comment: @swasheck I was referring to the question, not you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Sum()` your results:

```
SELECT h.Hotelname, Sum(r.FreeRooms) as FreeRooms
FROM hotel h
INNER JOIN hotel_room r 
    ON r.H_ID = h.H_ID
GROUP BY h.Hotelname
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT h.Hotelname,
       Sum(r.FreeRooms) as Total
FROM   hotel h
       INNER JOIN hotel_room r
         ON r.H_ID = h.H_ID
GROUP  BY h.Hotelname
```

Comment: WHERE clause is useless, see INNER JOIN

Comment: @tombom I'd already edited it before you posted - but thanks!